# Make java.text.DateFormat parse to java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format, date-parsing

Usually, I was doing it like this:

```java
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = f.parse("2012-12-21");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
bean.setDate(c);
```

But I just found that working solution:

```java
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
f.parse("2012-12-21");
bean.setDate(f.getCalendar());
```

Why nowhere in the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), it is specified that [`parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) (for exemple) *keeps in mind* the value after parsing instead of simply returning it? Is it a bad way to do? I feel like having been betrayed all these years long...

Comment: It might work, but the API states that parse returns the parsed Date. I would rather depend on a public specified API than an implementation detail that might change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calendar is mutable, if you parse a new date with the same SimpeDateFormat instance your bean's date / calendar may change

Answer (score 2):

I think it is bad. `DateFormat` has `Calendar` instance which is used to set date during parsing. This instance can be set with `setCalendar` method, if you want to do instance for another locale for example. After parsing date this instance simply stay in previous state and that is in current implementation, in future this value maybe cleared after `parse` method returns so I would not rely on this implementation. `getCalendar()` is in fact used so you can see what is current "kind" of `Callendar` in use, which locale and so on, but not for getting current value.

Answer (score 0):

i think you needn't to create instance from Calendar and use dateFormat directly:

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
f.format(f.parse("2012-12-21"));
bean.setDate(f.getCalendar());
```